# Why are UDP Packets not Sent from a Client Web page to a Server Using PHP fsockopen?

Tags: php, web, udp, client, fsockopen

The following code sends out a UDP packet when I run it from my Linux server with the address of my web client udp://192.168.1.107:2159.  However, when I call the same web page from the client with the address Linux server address shown in the code, NO UDP packet is emitted.  I tried both a PC client with chrome and a Mac client with Safari.  Also, the phpinfo() shows that allow_url_fopen is "On".  Also, I tried the code without the fflush() function too.

Is there restrictions on Client web pages and PHP sockets?  I don't see this searching the net.  By the way, I coded a Java app on the same client machine and it sends the UDP packet to the address and port without problem.

```
phpinfo();

$errno = 0;
$errstr = "";
$fsocket = fsockopen("udp://192.168.1.103:2195", $errno, $errstr);
if( !$fsocket ) {
    echo "$errstr( $errno)<br/>\n";
} else {
    $out = "Oh ya baby!\r\n";
    fwrite( $fsocket, $out );
    fflush( $fsocket );
    fclose($fsocket);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The port is the **second** argument to [`fsockopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php). It needs to get passed isolated from the domain name. Like this:

```
$fsocket = fsockopen("udp://192.168.1.103", 2195, $errno, $errstr);
```

Comment: Thank you but I have tried that version of the call too and I am not getting the packets out.  I wonder if it is a PHP setup for some other system configuration?

Comment: Here is the text of what I tried... [code]$fsocket = fsockopen("udp://192.168.1.108", 2195, $errno, $errstr, 30);[/code]

Comment: No, it should work. Please setup a udp test server on a second terminal on the same host first to get sure that no firewall forbids access: `nc luv 2195`. Then on the other terminal run your php script using `udp://127.0.0.1` and port `2195`. It worked on my computer, where I've didn't modified the `php.ini`. Check this: http://radarearth.com/content/using-netcat-udp-port-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

The issue... You can't always believe Wireshark!  I trusted Wireshark too much.  I created a Java application to receive from the Web based PHP fsockopen packet transmission.  Low and behold, Java catches the packet and Wireshark missed the packet  - every time too. The Wireshark case that failed was Mac (client PHP web call), Linux (Wireshark session and PHP web server).

I don't know if Wireshark labels the packet as something else or there is something obscure in the PHP generated packet as far a Wireshark is concerned?  The weird thing is when I transmit the same packet from a Java application Wireshark catches it!  I do not know all the reasons why.  But I got PHP fsockopen to work so my job is done! It works between Linux and Mac OS 10 in all combinations of client and server, so great!